# Java, fill an array with a supplied number

Tags: java, arrays, loops, arraylist, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.*;
public class IncreasingSum
{
    public static void ArrayList(int[] args)
    {
        Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number:");
        int num=kb.nextInt();
        {   for (int loop=0; loop<num; loop++)
            ArrayList <X> myList = new ArrayList<X>();
            myList.add(loop);
        }
    }
}
```

I have imported the java.util.*; but it keeps giving error on ArrayList.

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem? Do you need any more help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues

- should be static void main(String [] args), instead of static void ArrayList(int [] args)
- X should be Integer
- Loop should be around the add(), not the new ArrayList()
- extra braces not required outside the loop

Possible flaw

- Code should should probably use add(n) rather than add(loop) to "fill" the array with the same number
- If above true then just use Collections.fill(myList, num); and get rid of your loop

Fixed

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IncreasingSum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number:");
        int num = kb.nextInt();
        ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int loop = 0; loop < num; loop++) {
            myList.add(loop);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Syntax Errors**

The reason you get an error on the ArrayList line is because of the way you've instantiated it.

Here's an example of how to use ArrayLists with generics:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html

Basically in your declaration, you'll need to substitute X with the class of elements you want to store in the ArrayList.  In your case that would be Integer.

```
ArrayList <X> myList = new ArrayList<X>();        //Throws error    

ArrayList<Integer> myList=new ArrayList<Integer>();  //Will suit your need
```

Once you've fixed the list declaration, you'll also need to fix the line with the for loop.  The starting braces of your for loop should come after the loop declaration to fix your other syntax error.

```
{   for (int loop=0; loop<num; loop++)   //Throws error for your program 

for (int loop=0; loop<num; loop++){      //The declaration you need
```

**Other potential errors:**

You'll also need to include the main method in the class to execute your program.

**FYI:**

Java convention for method names is starting with a lowercase letter.  So even if you did have a method called ArrayList, arrayList would be more in line with the method naming convention.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Answer (score 0):

Use specific class called Integer for generics as you are adding Integer within array list before for loop and add element within loop:

```
ArrayList <Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need brackets after for loop. Right now the only intruction in for loop is to create new ArrayList several times. Array list should be declared above for loop.